# Overwrite repository definition in gradle subproject

Tags: gradle

Imagine you have a gradle build with a gradle subproject.
This subproject has some applied script plugin which define their own repositories like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        //jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://example.com/plugins.gradle.org/m2/'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.asciidoctor:asciidoctor-gradle-plugin:1.5.3'
    }
}
```

Now imagine you only own the main project, not the sub project (it is a git submodule).

How can you override the repository definitions of the subproject from the main project?

PS: if you need a better description of the subproject, here it is: https://github.com/docToolchain/docToolchain

**Update:** I've created an example to paly around with: https://github.com/rdmueller/SO56283254/blob/master/README.adoc

see the readme for more details

Comment: what you try to achieve looks similar to (unresolved) feature request like https://discuss.gradle.org/t/configure-buildscript-repositories-for-all-project-globally-in-init-gradle/6572/4 . not sure something has been implemented in Gradle to make this possible

Comment: @M.Ricciuti I guess you are right - so thanx for the valueable input. If you copy this as an answer, I guess I can assign the bounty to you!

Comment: I'm not 100% sure it's not possible, so I won't write answer . hope that someone else will have a magic trick to help you implementing this.

Comment: Hi. I had a deeper look and it really does not seem possible to implement. I wrote an answer

Comment: Thanx to everybody in helping me with this question!

Comment: Resolved it with dependencyResolutionManagement as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/76337036/6318705

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in my previous comment, you are in the same situation as described in issue/request 
 https://discuss.gradle.org/t/configure-buildscript-repositories-for-all-project-globally-in-init-gradle/6572/2,  which has related opened issue https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1038 . Unfortunately this issue has not been solved yet.

I had a deeper look and it seems to me impossible to make this work with current Gradle version:  there is no way to "alter" the script plugin's `buildscript` block by somehow injecting other `repositories`, so Gradle won't be able to compile this script plugin before applying it to the subproject.

Answer (score 3):

I believe I have a solution for the scenario described in the question (but note the caveat below!). You can put something like the following into your `settings.gradle` file of the root project:

```
gradle.allprojects { project ->
    if (project.path == ':subproject') {
        project.buildscript.repositories { repos ->
            all { repo ->
                // filtering by repo name here; you could certainly also use
                // the URL or other properties
                if (repo.name == 'maven') {
                    remove repo
                    // TODO replace with the repo you need here:
                    mavenCentral()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As [M.Ricciuti’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56356435/1797912) says, the caveat is that this *won’t* work for buildscript repositories in script plugins like the one you apply to the subproject of your sample GitHub project (`apply from: 'scripts/AsciiDocBasics.gradle'`).

Comment: Please note that you don't need to remove existing repositories from the `buildscript`, just add the new one, it will be used if the original one is not valid/reachable. But as you said, this does not answer the question, because here the main point is to make this work for applied script plugins.

Comment: @M.Ricciuti: well, the **original question** before [you have edited it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56283254/revisions) didn’t mention the script plugin. Only the GitHub example contains the script plugin. That’s what I’ve mentioned in my answer and hence I said my answer was a solution to the OP’s question before your edits.

Comment: I also posted a previous answer (which I have deleted since) because I was also misunderstanding the real problem behind the original question like you . that's why I made an edit to the question , to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

I've just tried a little, while I have no project where the sub-projects would feature a build-script:

```
// this lists buildscript repositories:  
getRootProject().getBuildscript().getRepositories().each { repo ->
    println "root: " + repo.getName().toString()
}

// this might list nothing:
subprojects.findAll { project ->
    project.buildscript.getRepositories().each { repo ->
        println "sub: " +  repo.getName().toString()
    }
}
```

The main problem might be, that this is being configured top-down; eg. passing a command-line argument which would apply an alternate `buildscript.gradle` block could work, but changing the root-project's configuration from within the scope of a sub-project won't. It might be rather uncommon, that sub-projects feature their own `buildscript` block (these Gradle plugin dependencies behave different than the regular Java dependencies - one generally can only decide where to apply them).

Comment: I tried to put your (modified) code into the `build.grade` but didn't succeed. Is the `build.gradle`the right location?

Comment: @rdmueller the root project's `build.gradle`. there might be other scripts, which set the `repositories` for sub-projects, which would have to be amended. the location does not even matter too much, but where it is being hooked into the task graph. [composite builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html) might be an alternative to that, because these offer the desired `dependencySubstitution`. see [Customizing Dependency Resolution Behavior](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/customizing_dependency_resolution_behavior.html).

Comment: please the me update above for example code. I think the main problem is that it is not about the subproject's dependencies but its plugin dependencies.