# Configuring Repositories for All Projects in Gradle

Tags: gradle

I am trying to configure repositories for all subprojects.

I have the main `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
        ...
    }
    dependencies {
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'base'
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'base'

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcentre()
        ...
    }

    wrapper{
        gradleVersion = '6.5.1'
        distributionType = Wrapper.DistributionType.ALL
    }

    dependencies {
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

In the subprojects `build.gradle` I just have:

```
...

dependencies {
    implementation ....
}
```

I am getting:

```
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
   > Cannot resolve external dependency .... because no repositories are defined.
     Required by:
         project :
```

I want to define `repositories` once in the main file as these do not change in subprojects.

---

In the `settings.gradle` of the main project I have:

```
rootProject.name = 'main-project-name'

include 'sub-project-name'
```

And in the `settings.gradle` of the sub project I have:

```
rootProject.name = 'sub-project-name'
```

Comment: This is great info.  Where is the "main" "all projects" `build.gradle` file located?  I can find a gradle `*.kts` file in my project folder(s) but can't find it for the entire Android Studio.  It will be difficult to understand and follow the answers if I only partly understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A multi-project build in Gradle may have multiple `build.gradle` files, but only one `settings.gradle` file (usually in the root project directory). Your second `settings.gradle` files defines a second setup that only contains a single project. You can check this by running `gradle projects`. Just delete the second `settings.gradle` file to solve your problem.

Usually you can simply define the names of your sub-projects by naming the respective directories and then calling `include`. The name of the `rootProject` may be defined inside `settings.gradle`, because the name of the directory is often not stored in version control systems like Git. Developers may check out the repository to different directories causing Gradle to use different names for the root project. If you want a subproject to have a different name than its containing directory, use `include` with the desired name and then change the project directory via `project(':foo').projectDir = file('path/to/foo')`.

Answer (score 0):

Modern Gradle versions provide a recommended way to declare dependencies in a centralized way.

TLDR: Use the [`dependencyResolutionManagement`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/initialization/Settings.html#dependencyResolutionManagement-org.gradle.api.Action-) DSL in your settings files to configure the repositories in all the subprojects. Both Groovy and Kotlin DSL look the same

```kotlin
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Read more in the docs: ["Centralizing repositories declaration"](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sub:centralized-repository-declaration).

Answer (score 0):

I resovled the problem, as you can see in my APP commit [RN 0.63.2 -> 0.70.5: fix Read timed out when compiling on Android](https://github.com/flyskywhy/ReactWebNative8Koa/commit/96fad3d9524e64fa309d0e72a4d9ad4808a1470f) , what I did is add below into `settings.gradle`:

```
// ref to https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sub:centralized-repository-declaration
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    // to fix `Read timed out` e.g.
    //    > Could not resolve com.facebook.react:react-native:0.70.+.
    //       > Failed to list versions for com.facebook.react:react-native.
    //          > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://maven.google.com/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml.
    //             > Could not GET 'https://maven.google.com/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml'.
    //                > Read timed out
    //    > Could not download bcprov-jdk15on-1.48.jar (org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.48)
    //       > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.48/bcprov-jdk15on-1.48.jar'.
    //          > Read timed out
    //    > Could not download guava-17.0.jar (com.google.guava:guava:17.0)
    //       > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/17.0/guava-17.0.jar'.
    //          > Read timed out
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.PREFER_SETTINGS)
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/google' }
        maven { url 'https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/jcenter' }
        maven { url 'https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/central' }
        // maven { url 'https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/gradle-plugin' }
        maven { url 'https://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public' }

        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        mavenCentral {
            // We don't want to fetch react-native from Maven Central as there are
            // older versions over there.
            content {
                excludeGroup "com.facebook.react"
            }
        }
        google()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

and now can also remove useless `allprojects` in `build.gradle`